# PostgreSQL: Copy data into another column with different data type

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. Now I have a table containing several columns. There are two columns I'm dealing with: *city* and *city_bak*. *city_bak* is of type integer and stores data of cities. The *city* column is currently null and is of type integer[]. What I want to do is to copy data from *city_bak* into *city*. Like this:

[PREVIOUS]

```
 |  city  |  city_bak  |
 |        |    100     |
 |        |    700     |
 |        |    1800    |
```

[AFTER]

```
 |  city  |  city_bak  |
 | {100}  |    100     |
 | {700}  |    700     |
 | {1800} |    1800    |
```

Normally when the two columns are of the same data type, I'd use

```
UPDATE {table_name} SET city=city_bak
```

But now they are different. How can I copy data in this scenario?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE {table_name}
    SET city = ARRAY[city_bak];
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!